# Plot a histogram of means and label individual mean/PDF

Tags: r, plot, rstudio

So I have this plot which is showing average scores of group of people. I would like to know how to, in the same picture, plot or lable X (see the picture, I added X with paint), where X presents the mean of one student compared to others.

My code

```
CairoPDF(paste('output/picture/', student, '_hist.pdf', sep=''), family='sans',)
hist(means.students.all, xlab="Means", main="Average Ratings")
dev.off()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two ways of adding a label. First, some random data and the regular histogram:

```
set.seed(0)
means <- rnorm(1000, 4.5, 0.2)
hist(means)
```

One way to add what you want is plot one point where you want, using `points()`

```
points(x=means[1], y=0, pch="X", cex=1.5)
```

Use `y` for the vertical position, `pch` for the type or character to plot, and `cex` to control it's size.

Another option, which gives you more possibilites, is using `text()`

```
text(x=means[2], y=0, label="StudentX", cex=1.5, srt=90, adj=c(0,0.5))
```

This way you can plot a full string (like the Student's name), rotate it 90 degrees using `srt` to fit the plot better, and align the text properly with left horizontal align and centered vertical align (this is related to the unrotated text) using `adj`. All of the above will result in:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer it helped me a lot. But I am generating pdf reports with latex and have for example in my data set average scores for 300 students. How would I define my code in histogram, so when I generate 300 pdf reports for 300 students, histograms and X labels will be labeled different that means that labeled X on histogram will be positioned different in histogram according to mean of [i] student.

Comment: More accurately: I have 3 variables: STUDENTS ID(300 different IDs of students)=(100,101,102....) CLASS ID (1000,1001,1002....) and the variable with which I drove Histogram of means: means.students.all. Now based on the variable STUDENTS ID and CLASS ID I would like to find the mean of [i] student and label it in the histogram of all means, that is, means.students.all. So in this way I will have 300 different labels of X for each student in same histogram.

Comment: I'm not sure I understood you, but you can select the mean of student `i` inside the call using `x=means[i]`. Whatever it is you use to loop through the students and generate a report for each one of them, you can use the same variable to select the corresponding mean.

Comment: Firstly, I would like to plot a histogram of variable "means.students.all" and label the mean of individual student according to the STUDENTS ID. So in the end I will have 300 pdfs with the same histogram(means.students.all) but different position of labeled X which is based on students mean in variable "means.students.all" and STUDENTS ID.

Comment: This is probably fit for another question, but, you'll use something like for loop: `for(i in 1:nrow(data)) { plot(...) points(x=mean[i], ...) }`. For more details on how to do it I adivse you to first write the full code of what you want to make for each student, for student 100, then try to transform that in a loop, and if necessary create a new question with the details.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply. I will first try myself and than ask a question.